# XSD make attribute nullable

Tags: xml, xsd

When creating the XML the attribute `wait` may not always contain a value. How can I edit the schema so it allows the attribute `wait` to contain either a number or no value?

```
<xs:complexType name="CommandType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="exe" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="args" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="wait" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="expectedOutput" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="toVariable" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I have tried doing both these `nillable="true"` `xsi:nil="true"` but they don't work. When I tried to validate the XSD I got errors.

Comment: Can I naïvely ask: why not make the `use="optional"` and interpret a missing attribute as `nil`? Is it that you want something explicit, to prevent unintentional missing attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"nillable" only works for elements, not for attributes - and even then it's not very useful because if the element is empty you have to add xsi:nil="true", which is completely redundant.

Either (a) define a type that's a union of xs:integer and a zero-length string, as suggested by IMSoP, or (b) define a list type with item type integer, minLength 0, maxLength 1. I prefer the latter solution as it plays better with schema-aware XSLT and XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way, but perhaps you could create a custom type that was either an empty string or conformed to the definition of `xs:int` using a `union` type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="emptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="0" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="intOrEmpty">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:int emptyString" />
</xs:simpleType>
```

Incidentally, it's worth remembering that the `xs:string` type includes empty strings, so if, say, the `exe` attribute should always have a non-empty value, you need a `nonEmptyString` type (using a `minLength` restriction) as well as marking it as `required`. I know that's caught me out in the past.